# React: multiple JSX templates for one single component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am a React newbie and I am developing a React application initially created using create-react-app module and I need it to be adapted to Mobile devices(browser)... For that I am facing the problem of having a Mobile and a Web version of the same component.
I was wondering if there is a way to optimise the process of two separate components by only having 2 different JSX rendering template and keeping the same code base. I mean loading specific JSX depending on device and place it in the render method.

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's certainly possible, might be an idea showing us some examples.   But making your website responsive takes this need away.

Comment: @Keith Responsive layouts is not the same of serving a specific mobile layout. A specific layout for mobile is needed when you have to deal in a complex UI (IE, in ERP software). Also, with code splitting made correctly, you can serve a lighter code to mobile devices.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini  I'm sure there are good reasons for mobile specific coding, but in most cases it's not the solution to the problem.  For example a user should not be penalised for web content because they are on mobile, this is bad UI design, and unfortunately it's done way too often.  There are so many websites I end up clicking the desktop version because of missing feature's / content on the mobile one, this is bad.  With responsive design, it helps to focus the design differently, and is less likely to penalise your mobile users.

Comment: Complex software need a specific mobile interface that cannot be accomplished with simple responsive solution. This is why *facebook mobile is not responsive*.

Comment: Why respinsive and why mobile: https://darwindigital.com/mobile-first-versus-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Thanks guys, I already found a solution concerning device detection. But, I found myself duplicating the same js code across multiple components, although all I need is a separate JSX template for each resolution.

For example: HomeComponent.render loads HomeMobile.jsx or HomeDesktop.jsx depending on user device
Can I achieve this process without duplicating my state, hooks and all of the this stuff in HomeMobile and HomeDesktop ?

Comment: @jemlifathi try to add some code, so i can show you how to. But maybe close this question and add a new one with code/more information.

Comment: @claud.io I created this pen https://codepen.io/jemliF/pen/LvdWRB
There is a sample code show case. You can see that I am duplicating state declaration and methods on MobileUsersCard and WebUsersCard components.

Comment: @jemlifathi yes, both MobileUsersCard and WebUsersCard are the same component, one solution could be to move you logic inside the component, i mean: in the parent component just render the same UsersCard twice passing to it a new props i.e. isMobile(true in one case and false in the other) and inside you UserCard component, depending on this props you can render different stuff

Answer (score 0):

Other answer rely on **screen size** (that can lead to false positives), this solution relies on detecting **mobile devices**

You can use [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect)

```
<BrowserView>
    <h1> This is rendered only in browser </h1>
</BrowserView>
<MobileView>
    <h1> This is rendered only on mobile </h1>
</MobileView>
```

This can wrap a single view or an entire set of routes inside a `<Switch />`

Answer (score 0):

try react-responsive library.

you can render the different component based on mediaQuery

[lib reference](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive)

```
import MediaQuery from 'react-responsive';

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <div>Device Test!</div>
    <MediaQuery query="(min-device-width: 1224px)">
      <div>You are a desktop or laptop</div>
      <MediaQuery query="(min-device-width: 1824px)">
        <div>You also have a huge screen</div>
      </MediaQuery>
      <MediaQuery query="(max-width: 1224px)">
        <div>You are sized like a tablet or mobile phone though</div>
      </MediaQuery>
    </MediaQuery>
    <MediaQuery query="(max-device-width: 1224px)">
      <div>You are a tablet or mobile phone</div>
    </MediaQuery>
    <MediaQuery query="(orientation: portrait)">
      <div>You are portrait</div>
    </MediaQuery>
    <MediaQuery query="(orientation: landscape)">
      <div>You are landscape</div>
    </MediaQuery>
    <MediaQuery query="(min-resolution: 2dppx)">
      <div>You are retina</div>
    </MediaQuery>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This is not a responsive issue, OP have to detect Mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Bootstrap. If this does not solve the problem. Then you can have some Flag State and have two functions returning different JSX markup. You will have to write logic for detecting Mobile.

Answer (score -1):

i'm using Semantic-ui React and there is a   Responsive component that you can render ad specific component and specify the resolution: for example

```
<Responsive as={Grid} {...Responsive.onlyMobile} columns='equal' >
   //stuff for mobile
</Responsive>

<Responsive as={Grid} {...Responsive.onlyTablet} columns='equal' >
   //stuff for tablet
</Responsive>
```

Comment: OP need to detect mobile devices, Responsive.onlyMobile and Responsive.onlyTablet are object that define responsive behavior, not device based behavior

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini "I am facing the problem of having a Mobile and a Web version of the same component" you didn't understood

Comment: Mobile and Web version is non a "Responsive version". I can have a mobile device with the screen size of a desktop. But is still a mobile device. Responsive is all about maxwith/minwidth media queries

Answer (score -1):

We can use **Rebass** library which is used to build the responsive component for mobile, tablet and desktop as well. Along with we can use **styled component**, so that we can easily style our component based on our own CSS.

https://rebassjs.org/

https://www.styled-components.com/